# How to Pass Props to Another Component In a Javascript Map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this code

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
import Storage from './Storage.js'
import {fetchStorage, loadAddStorageModal, selectStorage} from '../actions/StorageActions.js'


class SideNavContainer extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {        
        this.props.fetchStorage();
    }
    render() {
             console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <ul id="slide-out" className="side-nav fixed">      
                {
                    var hold = this.props;
                    this.props.storages.fetchedStorages.map(function (storage, i) {
                        return <Storage key={i} >{storage.name}</Storage>
                    })
                }
                <li>
                    <a className="waves-effect waves-light" onClick={() => this.props.loadAddStorageModal(true)}><i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">Add</i></a>
                </li>
                <li className="hide-on-large-only"><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
                <li className="hide-on-large-only"><a href="/Account/SignOut">Signout</a></li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        storages: state.storages
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchStorage: fetchStorage, loadAddStorageModal: loadAddStorageModal, selectStorage: selectStorage }, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(SideNavContainer);
```

I am trying to pass "this.props" into my Storage Component. I tried to do

```
 return <Storage {...this.props} key={i} >{storage.name}</Storage>
```

but I believe scope has changed so that does not work anymore. I tried to put it in a variable called "hold" but that just crashes the entire application as it says "var" is an Unexpected token.

Comment: Try moving the `var hold = ...` to before the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fat arrow style function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to auto-bind `this`:

```
this.props.storages.fetchedStorages.map((storage, i) => {
  return <Storage key={'storage-' + i} {...this.props}>{storage.name}</Storage>;
});
```

Comment: cool. I was just looking and I think passing all of the props is over kill. How could I just pass in selectStorage from action creator?

Comment: I can get it with the using "bind" {this.props.selectStorage.bind(this)} but I can't get it with using auto bind. Maybe I did not do it right